# Open page with "?data=data" like youtube.com/watch?v=videoID

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an html detects this? For example, I have a game in html, can I save the score to url like "example.com/game?score=15", detect this and set score to information in url? Or at least something like that? If you know what it's called, please tell...

I *tried* to search (cause I don't exactly know what it is) in google and youtube but no answer.

Comment: `const score = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("score");`. These parameters are not really for “storing” things. Storing is done with the [Local Storage API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are what are known as Request Parameters.